# Generation and Compilation of .resources files with MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, localization, embedded-resource

I have a process where I need to automate the process of generating the satellite assemblies. Specifically this is for WPF and combining Resx and BAML resources.

I've got a build script that works, but it requires manual adding of the .resources files I want to combine with the BAML resources. IOW, I have to add to the build script each time I add a .Resx resource. Not cool!

Currently I'm running the assembly linker manually and the script looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- Adds the build action 'LocBamlCsv' -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <AvailableItemName Include="LocBamlCsv" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <Target Name="CreateSatelliteAssemblies"
          DependsOnTargets="$(CreateSatelliteAssembliesDependsOn)">

    <!-- Locbaml needs the runtime assemblies in the intermediate dir -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\Tools\LocBaml.exe"
          DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />


    <!-- generate a .resources file for .csv merged output -->
    <Exec Command="LocBaml /generate ..\..\$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName).g.$(UICulture).resources /trans:%(LocBamlCsv.FullPath) /out:../../$(IntermediateOutputPath) /cul:%(LocBamlCsv.Culture)"
          WorkingDirectory="$(OutputPath)"
          Outputs="$(OutputPath)%(LocBamlCsv.Culture)\$(TargetName).$(UICulture).dll" />

    <!-- Generate the resource assembly by merging all .resources files -->
    <!-- NOTE: Explicitly add any resource files here -->
    <Exec Command="al /template:$(TargetName).exe /culture:%(LocBamlCsv.Culture) /out:%(LocBamlCsv.Culture)\$(TargetName).resources.dll /embed:$(TargetName).g.%(LocBamlCsv.Culture).resources /embed:$(TargetName).Properties.Resources.%(LocBamlCsv.Culture).resources"
          WorkingDirectory="$(InterMediateOutputPath)"
          />


  </Target>
</Project>
```

As mentioned it works. but the last command that calls al would be much easier to work with if there was some way to use wild cards (ie. $(TargetName).*s.%(LocBamlCsv.Culture).resources.

I've tried a number of things. Using the  build process apparently fires at the wrong time and it ends up failing to find files.

Comment: You can always write a script that scans the directory for *.res or whatever and generates the build script.

Comment: Jeff any links on how to do that? I'm not up to speed on msbuild and I'm not sure how I can get the files and pipe them into the linker path.  The other issue is that the  <AL> section doesn't work (even with hardcoded filenames - presumably because the timing in the build process where these files are available is wrong) where the explicit command does.

Comment: Sorry, no.  That's why its a comment instead of an answer. :)  But you know, perl or python and just add your files to the build script instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: Yeah I'm using a batch file right now to do this and it works, but it's pretty ugly. A generic build task would make this a lot nicer. I'm having real issues finding decent docs on msbuild and the individual switches available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is 
but you did say something that makes me wonder. *"Using the build process apparently fires at the wrong time and it ends up failing to find files."* From this I get the impression that you are trying to create an item which contains files that are generated during the build process. If this is the case then you should declare those as **dynamic** items, which are items declared **inside** of a target. Items declared outside of targets (**static** items) are evaluated before any target begins to execute. See my blog post [MSBuild: Property and Item Evaluation.](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,cf51471f-479a-4b6c-af97-896167871520.aspx)

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: Sayed thanks for your tip. This did end up pointing me in the right direction although this wasn't the exactly problem. The issue is that I build my resource assembly into the intermediate folder and apparently the normal build process would overwrite it. 

I change my code to write the final assembly directly into the target output satellite folder and that now works reliably. Not sure why *that* doesn't get overwritten, but it seems to work.

Will check out your book. Glad to see there's one on MsBuild - last I looked there was nothing.